# Hiding the base map in Google Maps V2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Does anyone know how to hide the base map in Google Maps V2? I've added the following lines in my attempt to remove the standard map types, but it seems to insist on showing some sort of base map:

```
map.removeMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
map.removeMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
map.removeMapType(G_AERIAL_MAP);
map.removeMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);
```

I'm adding a KML-overlay using GGeoXml, and that's basically all I want to show. I've also tried to add a blank white KML-layer between the base map and the actual data, but with no luck. Anyone out there who knows how to hide or disable the base map?

Comment: you may want to try openstreetmap; it's more customizable.

Comment: thanks cweiske, but it's too late to switch strategy for this project now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone's having the same issue, I ended up solving it by simply making all the Google-generated map images transparent using jQuery:

```
jQuery('#map img').css('opacity', '0').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=0)').css('-moz-opacity', '0').css('-khtml-opacity', '0');
```

The selector finds all img-tags below the map div id and sets opacity to 0 in most browsers. Left to display on the map is only the KML overlay, which was just what I wanted.

Comment: You'd be better to make your own blank map type (for example, one where every tile is a transparent or plain-coloured image). Hiding every image in the map might interfere with other things you plan to use - like markers or controls (and some map type tiles might not be painted as image tags in some browsers - they could be `<div>` with CSS backgrounds).